# mailto and redirect together

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i want to do submit and after if isset $_POST :

```
mailto fonction
mysql query SELECT.
do refresh.
```

but  one of these not work,

my example:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header("location: mailto:mail@domain.com" );
    mysql_query("UPDATE  bla bla bla");
    header("location: index.php....." );
};
```

idea is click on the button, open outlook window, do mysql update and refresh.

without refresh its work.

without mailtto also  work.

but 3 function together

TNX

Comment: Two redirects is imposible.

Comment: Do a sendmail instead!

Comment: important open Outlook

Comment: You should use `mailto:me@email.com` in HTML on an anchor .. `<a href="mailto:..."` and trigger ajax onclick of that element to record it in your database

Answer (score 1):

This will fail. You need to send the mail in another method, don't use:

```
header("location: mailto:mail@domain.com" );
```

Try something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  mail("mail@domain.com", "Form Posted Response data", print_r($_POST));
  mysql_query("UPDATE  bla bla bla");
  header("location: index.php....." );
};
```

And as always Do Not Use MySQL - it is no longer supported. Switch to MySQLi or PDO and start using Prepared Statements to protect from Injection.